# parallel uglify webpack module

Tags: node.js, webpack

I use the current uglify module has follows

```
uglifyPlugin = new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        sourcemaps: false,
        compress: {
            warnings: false
        }
    }),

 plugins: [
            commonsPlugin,
            dedupePlugin,
            uglifyPlugin,
            fnCaseSensitivityPlugin,
            sourceMapPlugin,
            fnDonePlugin
        ]
```

I want to use the parallel uglifyPlugin, how can I do so? 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-parallel-uglify-plugin

I'm confused

Answer (score 0):

First install the plugin with npm.

```
npm install --save-dev webpack-parallel-uglify-plugin
```

Then replace the uglify plugin that you're currently using in your webpack.config.js file.

```
const ParallelUglifyPlugin = require('webpack-parallel-uglify-plugin');
const parallelUglifyPlugin = new ParallelUglifyPlugin({});

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    commonsPlugin,
    dedupePlugin,
    parallelUglifyPlugin, // <-- new plugin
    fnCaseSensitivityPlugin,
    sourceMapPlugin,
    fnDonePlugin
  ]
};
```